# git command to download branch files without repo?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for something equivalent to manually going to a github repo and downloading a branch in a zip file without downloading the history (though it can just download the files without the zip file).

I've found `git clone --depth 1 -b <branch> <repo_url>` but I don't want to create a new repo on the local machine, I just want the files. I'm thinking using `wget` and `unzip` is a better option, but I'm not super familiar with git so I want to make sure I'm not missing anything first. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe use git archive with the --remote option https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: All data related to the git repo is in the `.git` directory, so you could just remove it after clone if you just want to keep the files

Comment: @bubulledu93 That's exactly the way to do it.

Comment: @truculence You probably don't want to do a simple clone for a few reasons, but the primary one being that it downloads the entire history by default.  Depending on the repo, that can be a lot of data for only one rev of history.  You can add some options to make it better, but `git archive --remote ... | tar xf - -C some-dir` is a much more efficient way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git provides a couple of ways to do this, and GitHub provides some different ways.

If you're working just with plain Git, you can do a shallow clone and then delete the `.git` directory, or you can do a shallow (and possibly bare) clone and then create an archive with `git archive`.  Both of those create a repository, but they are the most lightweight way using plain Git that works almost everywhere.

If you're using an SSH remote, you can try `git archive --remote`.  Not all servers support this, and notably GitHub does not.  It also does not work over HTTPS at all.

If you want a solution specific to GitHub, you can use [the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive) to download an archive.  You can specify an arbitrary commit, tag, or tree.  You will, however, need to configure your HTTP client to follow redirects and appropriately authenticate if the repository is private.